# How do I ProgressBar Circle and Rounded Corner (Android) Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I managed to circle the progress bar, but I can't round the corner
How do I leave the round corner without using any new library

I have already used the corner radius tag but there is no effect

Please would someone know to inform me?

My progress bar style

```html
    <style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_circular</item>
        <item name= "android:max">60</item>
        <item name="cornerRadius">@dimen/corner_radius_large</item>
    </style>
```

My ProgressBar

```xml
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBarWallet"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size_progress_validation2"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding_size_progressBar"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_progressBar"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_size_large"
                style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

My Drawable

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="16"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color ="@color/cyan_light"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="270"
                android:toDegrees="270">
                 <shape
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:thicknessRatio="16"
                    android:useLevel="true">
                    <solid android:color ="@color/cyan"></solid>
                </shape>
            </rotate>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the official `CircularProgressIndicator` provided by the Material Components Library.

Use the **`trackCornerRadius`** to change the rounded corners of the indicator.

Something like:

```
 <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
            android:progress="75"
            app:trackColor="@color/...."
            app:indicatorColor="@color/...."
            app:trackCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:indicatorSize="100dp"
            app:trackThickness="10dp"/>
```

[image]